# Boostrap Navbar/Sidebar issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Since i tried the style Sandstone, the Sidebar is a bit to high/Navbar runs into the sidebar. Same with the dropdown on the left side.

[image]

[image]

Sandstone: https://bootswatch.com/sandstone/
Template: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/

I tried already set max-heigh: 50px; but which breaks the mobile, design because it needs to be extended cause of the right dropdown.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without providing a fiddle or some tried out code, no one could help you here. please provide them

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to set `max-height:50px` but with `@media-screen` css rule?

For example: `@media screen and (min-width: 769px){#sidebar{max-height:50px;}}`